# Pull data from SharePoint On-Premises to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, bcs

I would like to pull data from SharePoint On-Premise (Custom List Data) to SharePoint Online. When searched on Internet most of the posts are suggesting like SQL Azure Connectivity between SharePoint On-Premise and SharePoint Online. I would like to know how to achieve this without using Azure as an interface. Is it Possible? If yes, how to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its pulling the list data and not replicating, you can configure [Hybrid federated search](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-hybrid-federated-search-for-SharePoint-4ee4b876-1673-4d1f-ba47-d9a0ef4474a9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) between the environments and create a result source specific to on-premises. Use this result source in Content search or Search result WebPart query and show the items.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh,Any step by step Sample to do this?How about data synchronization? Newly added item will be available in SharePoint online if it's added in SharePoint on-premises?

Comment: In that case you can write a event receiver for your on premises list and in item added event., use csom or rest API to create items in SharePoint online list. You need also need take care of update and delete too.